# How to hide one part of URL and redirect it?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have URL segment:
http://www.site.com/loadContent/contact/4

I want to hide the ID 4 in browser address bar:
http://www.site.com/loadContent/contact

Both contact and 4 are loading dynamically

How can I do that in my code?

Updated:

I have to passe $pageID as second parameter

I have a function that generation menu list items:

```
function buildListItem($item) {
$urlItemName = url_title($item->name, 'dash', TRUE); 
$urlCatID = ($item->cat_id);
$url = base_url() . $urlItemName . "/". $urlCatID;

if ($urlItemName == 'blog') {
    $blog = "http://blog.tumblr.com";
    return anchor($blog, strtoupper($item->name), 'target="_blank"');
} else {
    return active_anchor($url, strtoupper($item->name));
}
```

}

```
public function loadContent($name, $pageID) {
    $data['title'] = $this->tabPageData;
    $data['tabMenu'] = $this->model->getAllMenuItems();
    $data['links'] = $this->model->getLinksURLIcon();

    $pageName = array('portfolio-1', 'portfolio-2');

    // Store pageID within Session
    //$sessionPageID = $this->session->set_userdata($this->uri->segment(2));

    // Check if $name is in array pageName, get the page content and its name
    if (in_array($name, $pageName)) {
        $data['tabPageContent'] = $this->model->getPageContentByPageID($pageID);
        $data['pageName'] = $this->model->getPageNameByID($pageID);
    } elseif ($name == 'contact') {
        // load Contact page
        $data['tabContact'] = $this->model->getContactByPageID($pageID);
    }

    $this->load->view('content', $data);
}
```

Comment: Can't you try hashing functions like sha1() or md5() to make the value obfuscated instead of hiding and retrieving ?

Comment: Are you trying to hide it for cosmetics? Or are you trying to prevent the user from seeing it?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent the user from seeing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first, get id number and save in `$_SESSION` and ofter this work, you use preg_match giving ,one string of url without id number .

in end you redirect url use `<?php header("location: ". $URL") ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Your Options:

1. Stick with GET, but hit a redirecting script/function, Store the value in $_SESSION and redirect back to page without the data on the url.
2. POST a form
3. Use cookies instead of $_SESSION(blech)

[edit]

**Reasonably Generic Code - Should work on most any page**

```
<?
session_start();

if ( count ( $_GET ) )
{
    $_SESSION['__get'] = $_GET;
    header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
    exit();
}
elseif ( array_key_exists( '__get', $_SESSION ) && count( $_SESSION['__get'] ) )
{
    $_GET = $_SESSION['__get'];
    $_SESSION['__get'] = array();
}


var_dump ( $_GET );
```

Note: the var_dump at the bottom will be showing $_GET on a page that doesn't have any URL params.

Note: this is one-shot.  a second reload of the script will show that $_GET has been emptied.  If you don't want this, remove the `$_SESSION['__get'] = array();` in the `elseif` block.

**[edit]**

Even better code with functions and GET param scoping per page (using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`)

The content-type: text/plain is to make the var_dump easier to read, nothing more.

```
<?
// no-get.php
session_start();
header( 'content-type: text/plain' );

noGet();
var_dump( $_GET );
forgetNoGetPage();
var_dump( $_GET );

/**
* noGet - saves $_GET values to $_SESSION and redirects to same page
* @requires Session to be started
*/
function noGet()
{
    // check count to see if there are fresh variables being passed to the script
    // if there are, we overwrite any existing page variables in the session
    // if we didn't do this, we could never pass new variables on the url to our scripts
    if ( count ( $_GET ) )
    {
        $_SESSION['__get'][$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']] = $_GET;
        header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        exit();
    }
    elseif (
        array_key_exists( '__get', $_SESSION ) &&
        array_key_exists( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $_SESSION['__get'] ) &&
        count( $_SESSION['__get'][$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']] )
    )
    {
        $_GET = $_SESSION['__get'][$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']];
    }
}

/**
* forgetNoGetPage - removes a page's $_GET values from the session and optionally redirects to the current page.
* @param String The page to remove entries for
* @param Bool Redirect after remove?
*/
function forgetNoGetPage( $page = null, $redirect = false )
{
    if ( $page === null )
    {
        $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }

    unset( $_SESSION['__get'][$page] );

    if ( $redirect )
    {
        header( 'Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question: why do u need to check count($_Get) to get the size? Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question with exactly how you're trying to get this to work with CodeIgniter?

Comment: reading through the input class code file in CI leads me to believe that if you use the above code before any attempts to use `$this->input->get()` should work just fine.

Comment: I have updated my question above. The problem is when I remove $pageID in the menuList I can't be able to get in my controller...

Comment: where are you calling the "noGet" function I posted above?

Comment: Sorry I was on holidays vacation. I had to find a way to rewrite your code syntax in CI cause it doesn't allow using _GET.

Comment: Ok I found another way to do what I wanted without using session and redirect simply passing $name and get $pageID from it. It's shooter and working...